# Allow user modify only objects created by this user

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way in Django to give user access to admin privileges by allow only editing of objects that were created by this particular user?

For example I want to give the user permission to create other users but I don't want to allow them to modify users created by admin or other users with this privileges.

I'm using django-admin so the question is in context of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should override the [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) and [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) methods on your `ModelAdmin` class.

For example

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and obj.created_by != request.user:
            return False
        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and obj.created_by != request.user:
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: So do you suggest to make a field `created_by`?

Comment: You will need to have some way of tracking which user created which object. A `ForeignKey` to the `User` table is probably the simplest solution yes

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the obvious way, actually. But are you sure that author is not tracked by default?

Comment: The built in `auth.User` model does not track it's creator. You would have to add this functionality somewhere